# ACF group content in Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor, acfpro

Elementor is great to link single ACF-field content.
But I need to combine some of them in the ACF Layout "group", so that it's easier for the customer to overview and edit the content.

But Elementor does not support ACF fields inside an ACF group – they simply don't show up in the Key-dropdown.

Is there a way to get that going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to document [Elementor Integration With ACF](https://docs.elementor.com/article/381-elementor-integration-with-acf) on Elementor official website, complex custom field types such as group, repeater haven't been supported yet.

But there is a way to get value from ACF group field, [see here(wordpress support thread)](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/acf-field-data-under-group-layout-is-not-found-in-elementor-dynamic-fields/). While I haven't tested it.

I know you may want to sort those fileds by categories or other taxonomies to get a better logic and cleaner interface. But this would also limit you to certain widget in 3rd party plugins. Built-in dynamic content is really handy, I don't think it's worthy to give it up by using ACF group field.

So I suggest you to use regular field types along with conditional logic(each of), it's a better choice at this moment though the interface would be messy.

Comment: Hej Stephen, thanks! 

I'll give it try, but you're right – less plugins is more :)